# CORS Options Preflight Hanging

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have a ASP Web API project that is being hosted over SSL.  I have another ASP MVC project that makes use of the API.  While debugging, I am seeing behavior where the OPTIONS requests are hanging often (but not always) and preventing the other calls from proceeding.

In the Chrome debugger, these are just shown as 'Pending'.  If launch Fiddler, everything works fine.  I see no errors at all, things just hang.  This fails before it hits the authorization code, so I can't even set any breakpoints.

Could this be a certificate problem?  Firewall?

Comment: Adam, can you please let me know if you're using this feature: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CORS%20support%20for%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API&referringTitle=Specs?

Comment: I am not using it.  I have tried a few things, but settled on the one from Thinktecture.  None of these packages changed the effect I'm seeing.

Comment: Mine is hanging as well.. Chrome's Option status is "Pending". It happens off and on for me. I'm also using an SSL (HTTPS) url with a subdomain. So I know the preflight request is failing.

Comment: I'm seeing `OPTIONS` hanging with firefox, with/without fiddler, and without SSL/TLS. Happens for about 3/4 of the requests. Frustrating as I have no idea how to debug this. The browser appears to have sent the request but breakpoints in the CORS handler are never hit. Running on full IIS, not IISExpress. Fiddler shows the request as being sent but not responded to so I guess that rules out the browser being the black hole.

Comment: How did you get the SSL certificate? Is it self signed? In other words, did it give you a warning and you had to accept the certificate manually the first time you visited the website? If so, then that would be the problem that your request is not going through. Try to test it with HTTP

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this: adding following node in web.config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
         <!-- your other handlers -->
         <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```